How to dry lettuce in a high volume setting?
I'm cooking for 30 in a remote location. I do not have a salad spinner. After I wash my lettuce and tear it up for salad, I've been gently shaking it with paper towels in a covered bowl. This is helpful, but not great.
How is excess water removal accomplished in a high volume setting, like a restaurant or a cafeteria?

Are you asking about a commercial setting or simply how to dry lettuce on a larger scale?

I've never worked in that sort of place, but I seem to remember some TV show where a chef out the lettuce in a clean cloth pillowcase, and then went outside spun it around (vertically, not horizontally).  I don't know if there was any specific technique to it, but i suspect that you might give a sharp tug as you're about to go up for extra force.

@Joe that’s the method I use for example when we’re on vacation and have only limited kitchen equipment available. Btw, horizontally works as well, but sends the droplets everywhere. (The underage kitchen helpers will jump on this task immediately.)

I've seen a commercial supplier of salad leaves use a brand-new top-loading washing machine that had never been used to wash clothes or anything else. Not ideal I suspect as the pipes won't be food grade (I think), but if only used to spin should be OK.

A "restaurant or cafeteria" would absolutely have a large salad spinner. I used to moonlight at the cafeteria of my daughter's school, we cooked for up to 400 girls, and I as the only man around was the dedicated salad spinner spinner, because once you load this thing with five or more heads of lettuce plus the water you plan on removing, spinning it does require some force. Do consider taking a spinner, a normal-sized one will be enough for 30 people.

"I do not have a salad spinner." - Obtain a salad spinner.

I expect better answers than "obtain a salad spinner." Which one holds 4 heads of lettuce and won't break in a month of near daily use?

I can’t give you a definitive answer about commercial settings, but I do have a recommendation how to can dry your lettuce relatively quickly and if you work in batches it should be fine even for 30 guests.
A clean tea towel can be a makeshift salad spinner - place the leaves in, grab the corners and start spinning, either vertically or over your head - think spinning laundry or a lasso. You could also use a small tablecloth or any clean and largish piece of lint-free fabric. Cotton is great.
I very much recommend doing this outside because the water will be propelled outwards in the direction you are spinning (check for bystanders). Also you don’t need too much speed or spin too long, or you risk bruising the leaves. A few quick swings usually does the trick.

Relevant video

Shaking in paper towels might be OK as a final step, but shaking in a colander or even a large sieve is more effective at shifting large amounts of water. That actually gets rid of the water rather than just capturing it in the same container as the lettuce, and avoids having to deal with a huge mass of soggy paper which you'd otherwise have to keep changing.
You can shake more vigorously with some form of lid, such as a (light, non-breakable) plate.

I use a colander and a sieve facing each other and held together. They're both roughly the same size and you can hold the handles of both to stop the lettuce from escaping while you shake.

@Richard that give a bit more room for movement so should be good, hopefully without too much water flying upwards

I tend to do it near family members in order to annoy them, but yes.

I've moved to coring, rinsing, breaking up heads of lettuce, then shaking water out by hand, placing lettuce on a clean flour sack towel, and shaking lettuce back & forth, to & fro, in the folded towel. That has worked best so far.

If on time restraints, I recommend cutting the lettuce in half placing flat side down, give each half a quick shake and pat dry with a tea towel.
